# Events and accessing the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm in my first year of web developementat uni, i have a relatively simple javascript assignment, part of which wants me to

'Write JavaScript code to output values of attributes 'role' and 'data-button-number' (use jQuery method .data) every time normal button (Button 0, Button 1, Button 2) has been clicked.'

my answer is the following code however it is failing tests when i submit, can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".btn-default").click(function () {
    console.log($this.attr( "role"));
    console.log($this.data("data-button-number"));
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sign-in">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p>
            <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="0">
              Button 0
            </button>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p>
            <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="1">
              Button 1
            </button>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p>
            <button class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button" data-button-number="2">
              Button 2
            </button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 Company, Inc.</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see in the console when you are testing it?

Comment: isn't part of learning is to debug your own code? by the way when you ask for help, at least write the error / exact problem you are facing. you don't really expect people to run your entire code and look for random bugs

Comment: `$this` is not defined anywhere, you should look at the console for errors

Comment: Also, within your context, `$this` is invalid syntax. It is either `this` or `$(this)`.

Comment: Does it pass the tests that you run yourself?

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $this
https://replit.org/data/web_project/19debf1c27b090cfe4939b4124d34eda/index.js:3:22
dispatch@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:12449
handle@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:9178
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $this
https://replit.org/data/web_project/19debf1c27b090cfe4939b4124d34eda/index.js:3:22
dispatch@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:12449
handle@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:9178

Comment: ^^ that is what the console tells me.

Comment: when i run tests i am told 
'console.log wasn't called on click a button'

and 

'console.log was called with a wrong message'

i should mention that this assignment is being done via a classroom on repl.it, i really appreciate any constructive criticism that is given, i have only been coding for around 6 months. 
when i run tests it comes back with 
'console.log wasn't called on click a Button.'

&

'console.log was called with a wrong message.'

which i find surreal, i am definitely calling console log on all buttons being clicked, no?

Comment: Sagiv b.g, i uploaded what i wrote to see if there was anything wrong with the code written, as for debugging my own code i've been stuck on this small part of the assignment for 2 hours, people pointing out your mistakes is as much part of learning. Forgive my naiveties, this is my first post on stack overflow, hopefully not everyone that answers my questions aren't as bitter as you